# Querying using Mongoose for all values of a specified nested object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am currently trying to query a MongoDB collection using Mongoose, and I am having trouble trying to convert this query into a useable Mongoose query.

The MongoDB CLI query is `db.events.find({}, {'first.points': 1, '_id': 0})`.

This works fine and returns what I would expect when I run this in the command line, I have tried several methods of converting this to a Mongoose query, my attempts so far are:

**Attempt #1**

```
Events.find({}).populate('first').exec(function(err, events){
    if(err) { console.log(err) }
    console.log(events);
});
```

This does not work and throws the error `Cast to ObjectId failed for value "10" at path "_id" for model "Event"` when the node server is started.

**Attempt #2**

```
Event.find({'first.points': "10"}).populate('first').exec(function(err, events)
```

This does not throw any errors, and it does return the values I would expect, however I am trying to return all the `first.points` values for all events, and I cannot seem to do this.

**Attempt #3**

```
Event.find({'first.points': "$all"}).populate('first').exec(function(err, events)
```

This also does not work, and was my most recent attempt at this issue, it again throws an error this time saying `Cast to number failed for value "$all" at path "first.points" for model "Event"`

I am not sure what else to try for this, I am unsure how to return all of the values without specifying which to look for.

**EDIT**

The model for Events is included below

```
var eventsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String, // The event name, with data type String
   date: Date, // Date with data type Date
   first: {
       points: Number, // The points awarded to the first place with data type Number
       house: String
   },
   second: {
       points: Number,
       house: String
   },
   third: {
       points: Number,
       house: String
   },
   fourth: {
       points: Number,
       house: String
   }
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `Event.find({}, {'first.points': 1, '_id': 0}, (err, events) => ...)` ?

Comment: Thankyou, this has saved me so much time and has solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to [naga - elixir - jar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7185241/naga-elixir-jar) for this answer.

`Event.find({}, {'first.points': 1, '_id': 0}, function(err, events) {...})`

This code returns the values that I needed, without errors and in the correct format.

*Note I have converted this away from an arrow function for clarity. Arrow function is here `Event.find({}, {'first.points': 1, '_id': 0}, (err, events) => {...})`*